# Deleting negated values from a list in Scheme

Tags: list, duplicates, scheme

*Resolution* takes a list and removes negated elements from that list. The negated form is represented by a list with `not` in its head. For example if I have `'(a (not b) c (not f) (not a) b e)` my output should be `'(c (not f) e)`. I have written functions `remove-x`, which removes an element from the list and `match?` which takes a value and returns the matching value in the list. If my value is `'a` it would return `'(not a)` from the list.

So my problem is in the resolution function. I want to find if there are any negated elements and if there are, I want to delete *both* the element and its negation. I also need a way to figure out how to return false if no changes were made to my list:

```
   (define (resolution? alist)
     (cond ((null? alist) '())
           ((not (equal? #f (match? (car alist) (cdr alist))))
               (and (remove-x (match? (car alist) (cdr alist)) alist) 
                    (remove-x (car alist) alist)))
           (else (cons (car alist) (resolution? cdr alist)))))
```

These two functions below work:

```
   (define (match? value alist)
    (cond ((null? alist) #f)
          ((and (list? (car alist)) 
                (equal? value (car (cdr (car alist)))))
             (car alist))
          ((equal? value (car alist)) (car alist))
          (else (match? value (cdr alist)))))

    (define (remove-x x alist)
     (cond ((null? alist) '())
           ((equal? x (car alist)) (cdr alist))
           (else (cons (car alist) (remove-x x (cdr alist))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution needs a bit more of work, I'd suggest writing more helper procedures. At the core, the problem to solve is how to find the set difference between two lists. Here's my shot:

```
; obtain the non-negated variables in the list
(define (vars alist)
  (filter (lambda (e) (not (pair? e))) alist))

; obtain the negated variables in the list
(define (negated-vars alist)
  (map cadr (filter pair? alist)))

; find the set difference between two lists
(define (difference lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1) '())
        ((member (car lst1) lst2)
         (difference (cdr lst1) lst2))
        (else
         (cons (car lst1) (difference (cdr lst1) lst2)))))

; build the resolution, traverse alist and for each member
; check if it's in the corresponding white list of variables
(define (build-resolution alist clean-vars clean-negs)
  (cond ((null? alist) alist)
        ((if (pair? (car alist))
             (member (cadar alist) clean-negs)
             (member (car alist) clean-vars))
         (cons (car alist) (build-resolution (cdr alist) clean-vars clean-negs)))
        (else
         (build-resolution (cdr alist) clean-vars clean-negs))))

; pre-calculate lists, call the procedure that does the heavy lifting
(define (resolution? alist)
  (let* ((vs (vars alist))
         (nv (negated-vars alist))
         (clean-vars (difference vs nv))
         (clean-negs (difference nv vs))
         (resp (build-resolution alist clean-vars clean-negs)))
    (if (equal? alist resp) #f resp)))
```

It works as advertised:

```
(resolution? '(a (not b) c (not f) (not a) b e))
=> '(c (not f) e)

(resolution? '(a (not b) c (not d) (not e) f g))
=> #f
```

Comment: Hi Oscar, thank you for your response! Can I ask some questions for clarification? For your 'vars' function why do you use lambda? I haven't used it yet, so I am not sure when/why we need it. Also, for your negated-vars function why do you do 'map cadr' ?

Comment: I'm using `map` and `filter` to speed up development, but they're simple to understand (check the docs). Basically, you pass a function that you want to apply to the list, in the case of `map` it gets applied to each element and returns a new list, in the case of `filter` it creates a new list with only the elements that satisfy a predicate.  For instance, `map cadr` extracts the variable of each negation, give it a try on the console to see what I mean

Comment: If using `map` and `filter` is problematic you can write an explicit recursion that does the same, it's boring to rewrite functions that already exist in the standard library, but I guess it's ok when you're learning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, which could be simplified by the use of `fold`.

```
(define resolution?
  (lambda (lst)
    (let loop ((todo lst)
               (result '()))
      (if (null? todo)
          (alist->list result)
          (let ((item (car todo)))
            (loop (cdr todo)
                  (modify-alist result item)))))))


(define modify-alist
  (lambda (alist item)
    (let ((key (if (symbol? item) item (cadr item)))
          (value (if (symbol? item) 'affirmed 'negated)))
      (let loop ((todo alist)
                 (result '()))
        (if (null? todo)
            (cons (cons key value) result)
            (let ((item (car todo)))
              (if (eq? key (car item))
                  (let* ((old-value (cdr item))
                         (new-value (cond ((eq? value old-value) value)
                                          ((eq? 'cancelled old-value) old-value)
                                          (else 'cancelled))))
                    (cons (cons key new-value)
                          (append result (cdr todo))))
                  (loop (cdr todo)
                        (cons item result)))))))))

(define alist->list
  (lambda (lst)
    (let loop ((todo lst)
               (result '()))
      (if (null? todo)
          result
          (let* ((item (car todo))
                 (value (cdr item)))
            (loop (cdr todo)
                  (case (cdr item)
                   ((affirmed) (cons (car item) result))
                   ((negated) (cons (list 'not (car item)) result))
                   (else result))))))))
```

Comment: what if it's `(resolution? '(a a a (not b) c (not f) (not a) b e))`? --- seems you need special data type such that `add1(a,b) = (1,b) ; sub1(a,b) = (a,-1) ; sum(a,b) = a+b ; zero = (0,0)`.

Comment: Could be, but the original question does not address this point. Does `(not a)` negate one instance of `a` or all instances? I don't know. Both interpretations seem valid.

Comment: I think multiplicity shouldn't matter.

Comment: @WillNess I have changed my solution accordingly. The only difference is in the procedure that builds the result list.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I still think the result for `(resolution? '(a (not a) a b))` should be `'(b)`, *not* `'(a b)`.

Comment: [I've simplified your code with some `fold`s](http://ideone.com/sPo6xL), as you said. Check it out. :)

Comment: @WillNess Why do you use `call/cc` to escape from the loop?

Comment: I want to cause the minimal disturbance to the alist structure. Without the escape, I'd end up adding the new entry into the list's tail, i.e. rebuild the whole list structure. But in this case, simple `cons` is enough - but we learn this only after having searched through the whole list. --- Similarly, I'm reusing the alist's tail after the matching entry.

Comment: ... *Similarly, I* wanted to reuse *the alist's tail after the matching entry*, so I've also switched from tail recursion (which would necessitate the call to non-standard `append-reverse`) to simple recursion, as per [the advice in SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append-reverse).

Comment: @WillNess Sorry, but I still can't see the point of using `call/cc`. You can `cons` the new value onto the original list in any case.

Comment: @WillNess At the point you exit the loop, `store` is in scope, so you can just `cons` the new element onto `store`, or am I missing something?

Comment: [line 31](http://ideone.com/sPo6xL): `(cons item (loop (cdr todo)))`: `loop` returns its value into a non-trivial context. Previous `item`s will be consed onto its return value. this happened because I switched from your tail-recursion into simple recursion, to avoid calling `append-reverse`.

Comment: @WillNess I see it now. But I'm not sure I like it better.

Comment: For my part I'd prefer to surgically update the list structure itself (the alist store is an internal value, nobody else is seeing it anyway). But it's out of vogue now. :)